# What are the ways in which chef can install/deploy new release?

Tags: chef-infra

Lets say I have a program binary "customcommand" installed at location "/usr/bin".

Now when the application team release a new binary, I want to update the binary at location "/usr/bin"

How to achieve the above scenario in chef ?

Comment: Let's remind SO is not a forum and is aimed at solving specific programming problems. Take the [tour] and read [ask] please. If you have open minded questions on Chef check http://discourse.chef.io but don't forget most people help on their free time, so help us help you by giving a clear overview on what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the usual ways by building packages that fit to your operating system (apt, yum, etc.), the best fit for your case is IMHO the [remote_file](https://docs.chef.io/resource_remote_file.html) resource.

An example would be the following:

```rb
remote_file "/usr/bin/example" do
  source "https://example.com/current/example"
  mode "0755"
end
```

If your server (the one behind `example.com`) supports `Last-Modified` or `E-Tag` headers, Chef will only download and replace the binary, if it was changed compared to what's on disks.

Besides this, there are many more, both complicated and safe, mechanisms, including using a version-dependent URL that you set based on an [attribute](https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html) or receiving the file from artifact stores like Nexus or Artifactory. The proposed method at least allows you to get started quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You use Chef to automate what you would normally have to do manually, so the question is, how would you normally manage that process? How do the application team release a new binary; is it checked into a repository somewhere with a new version number, do they just place a new version into a shared directory or do you just get an email?

Ideally they are putting it into some kind of package repository (ruby-gems, for Linux something like RPMs or deb, for Java related code something like Maven or Ivy, etc, there are many others across different OS and languages). Either the chef [package](https://docs.chef.io/resource_package.html) resource will have support for it, or there is likely a [community cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/) for it. You can use these to specify that which version you need of the binary.

If it's just a file in a shared location, then you can use the chef [file](https://docs.chef.io/resource_file.html) resource to "sync" your version and the official version, but bear in mind this is quite horrible (no version checking, no safe-guards against downgrading, just "sync these two files")

If it's a manual process involving emails or similar, you need to automate that process first, I would say :-)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this will be using data bags to provide package information, environment file and the remote_file resource to perform the actual deployment.

As an example, lets say you want to deploy "customcommand" version 2.32 from nexus to the dev environment.

Step 1: Create a data bag named "dev" and an item with the package information:

```
"id": "deploy",
  "package": [
    {
      "name": "customcommand",
      "version": "2.32",
      "type": "bin"
    }
  ]
```

Step 2: Create a dev environment file that will be used during converge eg: `chef-client -E dev -r "recipe[name]"`

Step 3: Create a chef recipe that pulls information from the data bag using `data_bag_item(data bag,'data bag item')['package'].each do |item|` and performs the deployment using the remote_file resource.

This way, you can deploy different versions of the program by updating the data bag.